# How do I configure email notification on new case comment in salesforce.com?

Tags: email, templates, salesforce

In salesforce.com, I have a workflow that triggers when a new case comment is added via the self-service portal.  The workflow rule updates the Case.Status field, which fires another workflow rule on the Case object itself.  The end result is an email to the case owner that is notified that a new case comment has been added.

However, I can't find a way of including the case comment itself in the email, so it's almost useless.  How do I include the most recent case comment in the email template?  I assume it's something like {!Case.CaseComment}, but I can't find it anywhere...

Help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know I'm stumbling across this way after the fact, but the answer is...

{!Case.Last_Case_Comment}

Comment: Thanks - that was indeed simple :)

Comment: The Comment needs to be submitted with "Public" checked in order for this to work.

Answer (score 2):

Wow, you're trying way to hard. Goto Setup -> App Setup -> Cases -> Support Settings and enable the "Notify Case Owner of New Case Comments" option.

Comment: This is indeed the obvious choice.  I have checked, and the option is checked... it just doesn't do anything.  Perhaps it's time to open a ticket with their support team :)

Thanks

Comment: Another issue I ran into:  If you submit the Comment for a Case you own, you won't get the e-mail.